# Как получить значение поля password?

Tags: javascript

Надо сравнить правильно ли пользователь ввёл подтверждение пароля, а у поля password почему-то нету value( Подскажите пож-та как это можно организовать? Или только через ajax?

Comment: кидайте код, как у поля password не может быть value?

Comment: есть у поля password value, проблема в вашем коде

Comment: Спасибо, проблема действительно в коде) А я искал-искал не нашёл очевидную ошибку( Задал вопрос, после она нашлась)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:password').val()
```